# stuck om DefaultDataTable component - can not find the error

Tags: java, wicket

Im stuck, cant find out what Im doing wrong here. I have read several tutorials about it and tried "their" version of how it should be done. Netbeans do not give any errors but my browser does.
Her is my code. Any hints are welcome

RegistrerteBrukere.java

```
    package com.myapp.wicket;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.wicket.PageParameters;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.DefaultDataTable;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.IColumn;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.PropertyColumn;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;

/**
 *
 * @author Bjørn J Aurheim
 */
public final class RegistrerteBrukere extends BasePage {

    private DefaultDataTable<Bruker> table;
    private int antallRekkerPrSide = 50;

    private BrukerProvider provider = new BrukerProvider();


    public RegistrerteBrukere() {
        super();

        // opprette testdata i liste for datatabellen


        // List<IColumn<Bruker>> kolonner = new ArrayList<IColumn<Bruker>>();
        List kolonner = new ArrayList();
        kolonner.add(new PropertyColumn<Bruker>(new Model("Fornavn"),"bruker","bruker"));
        kolonner.add(new PropertyColumn<Bruker>(new Model("Etternavn"),"etternavn","bruker"));
        kolonner.add(new PropertyColumn<Bruker>(new Model("Telefonnummer"),"telefonnummer","telefonnummer"));
        kolonner.add(new PropertyColumn<Bruker>(new Model("Mailadresse"),"mailadresse","mailadresse"));
        kolonner.add(new PropertyColumn<Bruker>(new Model("StartDato"),"startdato","startdato"));
        kolonner.add(new PropertyColumn<Bruker>(new Model("Passord"),"passord","passord"));
        table = new DefaultDataTable<Bruker>("brukertable", kolonner, provider, antallRekkerPrSide);
        add(table);

        }


    public RegistrerteBrukere(PageParameters params) {


        //TODO:  process page parameters

    }
}
```

**RegistrerteBrukere.html**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>RegistrerteBrukere</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <wicket:extend>
            <table wicket:id="brukertable" class="brukere"></table>
        </wicket:extend>

    </body>
</html>
```

BrukerProvider.java

```
public class BrukerProvider extends SortableDataProvider<Bruker>{
Bruker u = new Bruker();
Bruker u1 = new Bruker(); 
private static List<Bruker> brukere = Arrays.asList( );

        public BrukerProvider(){
            setSort("fornavn",true);
            u.setForNavn("Tore");
            u.setEtterNavn("Hansen");
            u.setTelefonnummer("99887766");
            u.setMailadresse("noen@home.her");
            u.setStartDato(new Date());
            u.setPassord("passord");
            brukere.add(u);
            u1.setForNavn("Hanne");
            u1.setEtterNavn("Ås");
            u1.setTelefonnummer("99324766");
            u1.setMailadresse("noener@homdfe.her");
            u1.setStartDato(new Date());
            u1.setPassord("passsdford");
            brukere.add(u1);
        }
@Override
        public Iterator<? extends Bruker> iterator(int first, int count){
          List<Bruker> data = new ArrayList<Bruker>(brukere);
          Collections.sort (data, new Comparator<Bruker>(){
        @Override
           public int compare(Bruker o1, Bruker o2) {
               int dir = getSort().isAscending() ? 1: -1;
               if ("fornavn".equals(getSort().getProperty())){
                   return dir * (o1.getForNavn().compareTo(o2.getForNavn()));
               } else {
                   return dir * (o1.getEtterNavn().compareTo(o2.getEtterNavn()));
               }

           }

        });
        return data.subList(first, Math.min(first + count, data.size())).iterator();
 }
@Override
        public int size(){
            return brukere.size();
        }
@Override
        public IModel<Bruker> model(Bruker object){
            return Model.of(object);
        }
}
```

**My error message:**

```
    WicketMessage: Can't instantiate page using constructor public com.myapp.wicket.RegistrerteBrukere()

Root cause:

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
     at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
     at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
     at com.myapp.wicket.BrukerProvider.<init>(BrukerProvider.java:29)
     at com.myapp.wicket.RegistrerteBrukere.<init>(RegistrerteBrukere.java:24)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:192)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:57)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:298)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1279)
     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1358)
     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1465)
     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:486)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:319)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Complete stack:

org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor public com.myapp.wicket.RegistrerteBrukere()
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:212)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:57)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:298)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1279)
     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1358)
     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1465)
     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:486)

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:192)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:57)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:298)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1279)
     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1358)
     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1465)
     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:486)



display page view
```

Hope this is enough information ..

Answer (score 6):

The problem is with your declaration of your list here:

```
private static List<Bruker> brukere = Arrays.asList( );
```

Contrary to what you might guess, [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) does not return an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Rather, it returns (to quote the Javadoc) "a fixed-size list backed by the specified array". The key phrase here is "fixed-size", which implies that you cannot increase or decrease the size of the array. In other words, the List returned by `Arrays.asList()` should be considered a Collection-like view of the array rather than a new list backed by an array.

You can fix the issue by simply changing the above line to:

```
private static List<Bruker> brukere = new ArrayList<Bruker>();
```

Which will use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), which is a proper full implementation of [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Incidentally, you might take a look at [this blog post](https://kamleshkr.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/inside-java-arrays-aslistt-a/) that delves a little more into the actual implementation of the class returned by [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29).

It's also worth noting that throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException` is [documented behavior for `List.add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29). This may seem to violate the expected nature of an interface, but the Java `List` class actually offers a number of methods (`add()`, `addAll()`, `remove()`, `clear()`, etc., basically, the methods intended to change the underlying stored list) that implementations can optionally not implement by simply throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. I did find this explanation on the Internet yesterday when I googled the error message. I just could not connect the dots...  :-)

Answer (score 0):

After changing the Arrays.asList to ArrayList I still had an error. It was corrected by replacing

```
 List kolonner = new ArrayList();
    kolonner.add(new PropertyColumn<Bruker>(new Model("Fornavn"),"bruker","bruker"));
    kolonner.add(new PropertyColumn<Bruker>(new Model("Etternavn"),"etternavn","bruker"));
    kolonner.add(new PropertyColumn<Bruker>(new Model("Telefonnummer"),"telefonnummer","telefonnummer"));
    kolonner.add(new PropertyColumn<Bruker>(new Model("Mailadresse"),"mailadresse","mailadresse"));
    kolonner.add(new PropertyColumn<Bruker>(new Model("StartDato"),"startdato","startdato"));
    kolonner.add(new PropertyColumn<Bruker>(new Model("Passord"),"passord","passord"));
    table = new DefaultDataTable<Bruker>("brukertable", kolonner, provider, antallRekkerPrSide);
```

with:

```
  `List kolonner = new ArrayList();
    kolonner.add(new PropertyColumn<Bruker>(new Model("Fornavn"),"fornavn","fornavn"));
    kolonner.add(new PropertyColumn<Bruker>(new Model("Etternavn"),"etternavn","etternavn"));
    kolonner.add(new PropertyColumn<Bruker>(new Model("Telefonnummer"),"telefonnummer","telefonnummer"));
    kolonner.add(new PropertyColumn<Bruker>(new Model("Mailadresse"),"mailadresse","mailadresse"));
    kolonner.add(new PropertyColumn<Bruker>(new Model("StartDato"),"startdato","startDato"));
    kolonner.add(new PropertyColumn<Bruker>(new Model("Passord"),"passord","passord"));
    table = new DefaultDataTable<Bruker>("brukertable", kolonner, provider, antallRekkerPrSide);`
```

In the RegistrerteBrukere.java file